# Are there reasons to use a redux store when data will only be necessary in a single component?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've got an app I'm building with some data that needs to be accessible in multiple components, so I'm putting it in a redux store.  However, I've got some data that will only be displayed in a single component.  Basically, a user can search for a business, click on the business to see its products, then click on a product to see any user-submitted feedback for that product.  The feedback will only ever be seen in the product component.

I don't really see any reason why I should put this data in the redux store, since I won't need to access it anywhere else, but I'm fairly new to React/Redux so I want to make sure I'm not missing anything.

Comment: Yes, but you still need a place from where you want to grab that data, even though it won't be accessible from other components.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit?  I was thinking I would just use useState in the component, make a call to the API when the component loads and update the component state with the fetched data.

Comment: One case or it could be usefull is if your call is slow and have high probability of having a similar data, then if you store in the redux. At this moment the second time the user will access your component he will quickly see information before the rest of the information will be updated

Comment: @bgfield, BryanOfEarth already said it all. I also prefer to keep everything in a store because components get really big and unreadable once you start keeping API logic and rendering logic altogether.

Comment: @faithfull that's a great point I hadn't considered - thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you will only be using "user submitted feedback" data within the product component, it's perfectly acceptable to keep this within your local component state.

If you think that there is a chance that *other parts of your app* may want to use this information in the future, then it may be a good idea to go ahead and keep it in the Redux store. Planning ahead, in other words.

Check out [this post from the Redux website](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state/), which talks about the issue you're having.

Comment: Thank you! I figured as much but I like to be sure I'm making the best decisions.  In regards to your second paragraph, if I took that approach and put the data in the store just in case, but it turns out I ultimately won't need to access it anywhere else, are there any performance issues to consider with keeping unnecessary data in the store?

Comment: It ultimately depends on your implementation. You can definitely do things within Redux that will cause worse performance, and usually it's because of re-rendering components too often.

Answer (score 1):

The primary appeal of putting data in the redux store is so you can access that data from any connected component that might need it.

If you're not using the data in any other component then I see no reason to put it in the redux store.

I would fetch the data from wherever you're getting it from when the component loads and store it in the state if it can be changed at all or in a const variable if no changes will be done to the data.